Best Way To Scrape/Extract Data From Wesbite - Find url via Chrome Network tools?
Below is the link to a webpage and a screenshot of the network tools that shows what occurs when clicking download csv -- what is the best way to write a script in python to return the data that shows in preview:
https://pjenlinea3.poder-judicial.go.cr/estadisticasoij/


You should first contact the site operators and ask if they have an API you can use. FWIW, the data is retrieved by an HTTPS POST request with a JSON payload containing parameters derived from the drop down boxes. You can see the detail in the network tab of your browser's Developer Tools. You might be able to POST your own requests direct to the address, but some APIs won't respond to non-browser queries.

@TangentiallyPerpendicular would you be able to share a screenshot or help me navigate as to where that is in my developer tools?

@TangentiallyPerpendicular I actually found the data I want to pull, it is not in my post / in screenshot -- how would I get the url or script in python to request it?

You'll need to figure out the details required to get the correct data via the data payload.
import requests

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
}

data = {
    "pJson": {
        "TN_FechaInicio": 20240101,
        "TN_FechaFinal": 20240625,
        "TC_Provincias": "2",
        "TC_Cantones": "0",
        "TC_Distritos": "0",
        "TC_Delito": "2",
        "TC_Victima": "1,2,3,4,5",
        "TC_Modalidades": "0",
    },
    "pExtension": "csv",
}
# Data needs to be a string.
data["pJson"] = str(data["pJson"])
data = str(data)

response = requests.post(
    "https://pjenlinea3.poder-judicial.go.cr/estadisticasoij/Home/obtenerDatosDescargas",
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
)

with open("pjenlinea3.csv", "wt") as file:
    file.write(response.text)


where can I find said details - in chrome tools?

Yes, that's right. I got the parameters above via the Network tab in Developer Tools.
